# The site crash when add a server

Tags: 8, search

I'm trying to use Search_api_solr and search-api.
I install the required modules and run the solr server and create a core.
But when I'm trying to add a server to my drupal 8 site, an error appears 
`Solarium\Exception\UnexpectedValueException: Neither collection nor core set. in Solarium\Core\Client\Endpoint->getBaseUri() (line 299 of /var/www/html/vendor/solarium/solarium/src/Core/Client/Endpoint.php).`

I try to change the following block in Endpoint.php file to my data but it's not working.

```
protected $options = [
        'scheme' => 'http',
        'host' => 'xx.xx.xx.x',
        'port' => 8983,
        'path' => '/solr/',
        'collection' => null,
        'core' => 'my_core',
        'timeout' => 5,
        'leader' => false,
    ];
```

also, should the host include the http:// or only the ip address?
However, I try all above with no luck.
Any advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you create an index in the admin? Why are you editing code ?

Comment: @kevin not yet. because when I read the Endpoint.php file, it includes localhost and null values, not my main values. I through that's causing the issue.

Comment: I don’t know what that file is. Read the README of those modules first. It’s configurable from the admin.

Comment: Yes, you should never need to touch any file under the vendor folder. If you look at the README, you'll see you need to install Drupal-specific configuration files in your core before it can be used, I suspect that may be your problem.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong thanks for replay. which README? Do you mean the search-api-solr README? yes I copy all files in /search_api_solr/solr-conf/7.x/ folder into solr-7.7.2/server/solr/my_core/conf

Comment: Yes, that was the README I meant. I don't know why you are getting the error adding the server. Have you browsed to the Solr admin web interface? Would be worth checking in case there's an issue there.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong yes I check the Solr admin interface, it's running without any errors when I check logging section.

Comment: The module README. Not just the solr conf.

Answer (score -1):

Collection is required in solr configuration. You'll need to create a collection you want to use for your site. Create using below command or by user interface of solr, then use the same name for the collection.

> sudo su - solr -c "/opt/solr/bin/solr create -c COLLECTION_NAME -n
>   data_driven_schema_configs" // Only for ubuntu

Replace COLLECTION_NAME with the name of your collection you want.